# Convertir algoritmo de SQL a Java

Tags: java, sql

Estoy tratando de pasar una funcion desde SQL a Java.
Esta genera un digito verificador a partir de un numero dado, ejemplo: 1234567-8, donde 8 es el digito generado.

El problema que estoy teniendo, es con los tipos de variables Integer, Double, Long etc, pues  hay funciones como Math.floor que retornan doubles, pero el dato que necesito es integer, o bien datos que son muy largos que deben ser Long, pero son incompatibles con parte del algoritmo.
Este problema lo tengo por que SQL no es rigido con los tipos de datos, pero Java si.

Alguno sabe como adaptar este codigo, si me puede echar una mano?

```
Begin
OUT_STRING  := ' ';

    numero := In_Num_Ruc; 
    z_aux := '2765432765432';
    suma := 0;
    i := 1;
    p := 1000000000000;
    d := 0;
    While i < 14 And p > 0 Loop
        d := floor(numero/p) - Floor(numero/(p*10))*10;
        suma := suma + d * To_Number((SubStr(z_aux, i, 1)));
        i := i + 1;
        p := p / 10;
    End Loop;
    d := 11 - (suma - Floor(suma/11) * 11);
    digito := Substr('123456789K0', d, 1);

    OUT_STRING  := digito;

Return(OUT_STRING);
```

End FN_Digito_RUC;

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Da más detalles, explica de que trata tu algoritmo, di que es lo que hace, en java puedes hacer lo que sea

Comment: Basicamente genera un numero extra a partir de otro numero más grande.

Al parecer es muy parecido sino igual al Algoritmo de modulo 11. Desconozco si es el mismo, ya que me solicitaron replicar ese codigo en Java, pero va en la misma linea.

https://validarutchile.cl/calcular-digito-verificador.php

Comment: Tu lo que quieres validar es ese Rut de Chile?

Comment: No necesariamente validar el Rut. Lo que sucede es que ese digito verificador que necesito calcular se calcula a partir de un numero generado a partir de 3 datos (numero institucion, año y num folio). Aquel numero generado a partir de esos 3 datos tiene un aspecto como 000000000000, y necesito calcularle el -0.
La logica es similar pero ese numero ( -0) se genera segun el algoritmo que puse, pero no logro convertirlo a JAVA.

Con ese numero obtendria algo asi  000000000000-0

Comment: Yo se lo que hablas y lo que es el módulo 11 eso se usa para validar desde cédulas de identidad hasta el isbn de los libros, lo que necesito es que detalles el algoritmo de validación que empleas, tal como se hace en el hipervínculo que pones del RUT, ahí se explica paso a paso que hay que hacer, así es como debes explicar tu algoritmo, recuerda que lo que tu estas haciendo solo lo entiendes tu, por eso debes transmitir la idea de lo que quieres hacer de forma clara para que otros la entiendan

Comment: No basta solo con poner el código

Comment: Entiendo, el problema es que no se exactamente como y por que pensaron ese algoritmo.
Este es un algoritmo de un sistema antiguo que tengo que pasarlo a uno más nuevo en Java, que genera un digito verificador a partir de un numero de folio previamente generado. El tema es que no sé si hubo algun razonamiento detras para el digito o bien quisieron hacer una variante del Modulo 11.

Mi complicacion esta en traducir dicho codigo desde la funcion en un package SQL a la implementacion directa en JAVA. Son los tipos de datos los que incompatibilizan.

Comment: Entonces edita tu pregunta y pon el algoritmo que tienes en el SQL tambien (de estar correcto ese algoritmo en SQL)